# Ubuntu DVD for Africa

Tags: dvd, custom-distributions

I live in Tanzania Africa and have been promoting Ubuntu for use by NGOs, Schools, and Friends. So far I've got a lot of positive feedback, but do have one huge problem. Internet here is both slow and very costly (up to $1,200 per month) So what I am looking for is a current release of Ubuntu which includes all the updates and popular applications already on it like; Gimp, VLC, Ubuntu Restricted files, Scribus, Inkscape, VirtualBox, Chrome, Audacity, Compiz, Blender, Ubuntu Tweak, Gnucash, Skype, etc... Basically all the 4 - 5 star applications. Does a hybrid DVD exist? I found links to one called Ubuntu Install Box 11.04, but not sure if they are truly legitimate. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Brendon

Comment: Making your own cd/dvd gets you into trouble: it -will- download the files from the web still using your internet line. Downloading the complete dvd will be quicker than creating your own version plus you can burn the dvd and share it with more Tanzanians ;-)

Answer (score 7):

[32 bits DVD download](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/natty/release/ubuntu-11.04-dvd-i386.iso) (3.9 Gb) and [64 bits DVD download](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/natty/release/ubuntu-11.04-dvd-i386.iso) (3.9 Gb) are the dvd downloads. This [listing](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/natty/release/ubuntu-11.04-dvd-i386.list) shows the content of the dvd and should have all the packages you need.

If you want to make your own CD/DVD with all the packages specifically mentioned in your question you need to make it yourself. Luckily for you I posted an answer on that: [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd/49679#49679)

Being in Africa you might want to try the [official Africa mirror](http://ubuntu.mirror.ac.za/)

Comment: Good guide, but I think it might be above my understanding. Do you know of any premade custom installation DVDs that fit the bill?

Comment: No and I do not think you'll find any either. Unless you make it yourself...

Comment: I've heard of some releases called "Ubuntu remix". But I can only find a swedish version of it, which is a bit pointless here.

Answer (score 0):

you can buy Ubuntu Installer and repository disc. I recommend you to buy Ubuntu 10.04 Installer disc at [canonical online shop](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17) and Ubuntu 10.04 Repository Disc at [on-disk](http://on-disk.com/product_info.php/cPath/28_135_183/products_id/1273). Hope this helps

Comment: Having the repository Discs would be good, but really I'd like to download or make a custom DVD with the above mentioned applications and Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/).
it is a back up tool and it enables you to create your own live cd of the current system you are using.
it is very simple to use, you can find the repository on the site .
once you've done your custom cd or dvd, you can copy it and distribute it as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use custom distributions based in Ubuntu, provided from enthusiast people from around the world, of which -in my humble opinion- the one that better fits all your needs is the [Israel Remix Team Distro](http://israelremixteam.com).

A pre-made custom distribution will include all these applications and a few more.

I know people will downvote this but may be a pre-made custom distro will be the best answer for this question.

Nevertheless, there are lots of custom distros that can be seen in [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/).

Take a look at those, of which I strongly suggest you the [Israel Remix Team](http://israelremixteam.com), based in Ubuntu.

Good luck!